# Angularjs - execute a common method before every other methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am building a website where users can view posts.

The posts are publicly available. The requirement is that i need to check whether the user is logged in on every user action.

For example, a user hits my website url www.mysite.com and views a post. The user is not logged in at this point. The user tries to like the post. Before the method for like is executed, i need to execute a method to check if the user is logged in. If not logged in, show login box. Same is the case for all user actions. Currently i have written as follows. Inside every method, i have to use checkUserLogin();

```
function likePost() {
   checkUserLogin();
   ...
}

function commentPost() {
   checkUserLogin();
   ...
}
```

If i have to do this in rails the code would have been like as follows.
Rails has a method called 'before_filter'. Using before_filter, we can execute a method before an action.

```
before_filter :checkUserLogin

def like_post
   ...
end

def comment_post
  ..
end
```

Only if the before_filter condition succeeds, the method(like, comment etc) will be executed.
In this case, i dont have to write 'checkUserLogin' inside every method. It will be taken care of by the before_filter.

Is there a similar kind of thing in angularjs?

Comment: Why do you want to check if user is logged in on user actions ? You can take this approach on every api call and check if user is logged in.